# VBA Macro not working in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

Ok guys, so I had a bit of trouble with my first post regarding this problem and I had received a ton of help. However we are still running into some trouble.

What I am trying to do: I have 4 listboxes on 4 different sheets. The list boxes are looking at a column that has a list of items. The Items where the listboxes are referencing have sub items. I want the list box (when clicking the item inside the listbox), to show the sub items in text boxes that I have on the sheet. I had some code that worked in the beginning, however, when I try to use it on multiple sheets it does not work.

The first block of code is what I was originally using, but I came on here and had some help that gave me the last 2 blocks of code; that should be working but are not.

```
Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim idx As Long

    If idx <> -1 Then
        idx = Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex
        Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").OLEFormat.Object.Text =   Sheets("sheet1").Range("Q" & idx + 1).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

This block of code is specific to each sheet. There are about 30 total text boxes that I will be referencing on each sheet. So in actuality the below will have 30 items.

```
Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", "Texbox1(sub-item)", "W"
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", "Texbox2(sub-item)", "X"
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", "Texbox3(sub-item)", "Y"
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", "Texbox4(sub-item)", "Z"
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", "Texbox5(sub-item)", "AA"
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", "Texbox6(sub-item)", "AB"
End Sub
```

This is code that stay in the VBA Module

```
Sub Handle_Change(sht As Worksheet, lbName, tbName, colAddr)

    Dim idx As Long, lb   As msforms.ListBox

    Set lb = sht.Shapes(lbName).OLEFormat.Object.Object

    idx = lb.ListIndex
    If idx <> -1 Then
        sht.Shapes(tbName).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text = _
                         sht.Range(colAddr & idx + 1).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

When I try to run it with the new code (last 2 blocks above) I get an error that says: "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" and highlights the second line of code on the Handle_change ", lb As msforms.Listbox".

Thanks for your time,

Good day

Comment: In your VBA IDE, you need to set a reference to Microsoft.Forms 2.0 Object Library.

Comment: I do not know how to do that, please advise, thanks.

Comment: What he said. =)  In the VBA compiler it is under Tools -> References

Comment: the easy way is to just add a UserForm and it sets the reference for you.

Comment: Should I insert the userform in the same module with the Handle_Change? When I tried to go to Tools -> references it was grayed out.

Comment: The other way to go about is in the VBA window, go to Tools => References => Browse...  In the open file dialog, and select the file //Windows/SysWOW64/FM20.DLL.  (This is on a Win7 64-bit OS, your location may be different, but the file you're looking for is FM20.DLL)

Comment: Userforms are independent of modules.  It'll go in it's own folder by default.  The userform is just a cheap trick to get the reference for you. Once you get the reference set, you can delete the userform.

Comment: Adding an ActiveX form control to a worksheet will automatically add the Forms library reference to your project.

Comment: Okay, so I added the Userform. It is still giving the same error.

Comment: it's case sensitive.  change msforms.ListBox to MSForms.ListBox

Comment: I actually had already done that... Still getting the error.

Comment: Can you confirm that the proper reference is checked? In the VBA window, go to Tools => References and confirm that the Microsoft.Forms 2.0 Object Library is checked

Comment: That might be the problem. References is grayed out.

Comment: Okay, I had to close VBA. I am looking for Microsoft.Forms 2.0 Object Library now

Comment: I have a Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library, but not Microsoft.Forms 2.0 Object Library in my references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I think this is what you need.

This goes in the worksheet code module: you need on event handler per listbox.

```
Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", _
       Array("Textbox1", "Textbox2", "Textbox3", "Textbox4"), _
       Array("B", "C", "D", "E")

End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
'### This code goes in a regular VBA Module ###
' sht        = sheet hostong the controls
' lbName     = name of listbox on that sheet
' arrTbName  = array of textbox names
' arrColAddr = array of column source addresses, matching order
'                of the values in arrTbName
Sub Handle_Change(sht As Worksheet, lbName, arrTbName, arrColAddr)

    Dim idx As Long, lb   As msforms.ListBox, i As Long

    Set lb = sht.Shapes(lbName).OLEFormat.Object.Object

    idx = lb.ListIndex
    If idx <> -1 Then
        'loop through the textbox and column arrays, setting each pair
        For i = LBound(arrTbName) To UBound(arrTbName)
            sht.Shapes(arrTbName(i)).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text = _
                    sht.Range(arrColAddr(i) & idx + 1).Value
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Sample file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15526711/Listboxes.xlsm

Comment: Tim, I haven't carried this over but I had a chance to fool around with it and this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot for your time. Good day

Comment: Tim, quick question, I have titles for the subitems. So, technically the items are looking at 1 above. How do I get the code to start referencing at row 2, rather than row one for the sub items. Not the subitems title?

Comment: `sht.Range(arrColAddr(i) & idx + 1).Value` >> `sht.Range(arrColAddr(i) & idx + 2).Value`